# Web Api 2 Help Pages & OAuth Endpoint

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I'm using ASP.net Web API 2 via VS2013 to create a private API for a project.  This is all working well, including the automatic Help functionality, with the exception of one thing:

The API is secured using OAuth 2.0 Resource Owner Flow and I want to include the "/Token" endpoint in the Help as without it there is a very important part of the API that is completely undocumented.

I can't see any way of doing this as it stands because the OAuth functionality is handled via the OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider class rather than a ApiController derived one, and hence it will never be included in the standard documentation.

Does anyone know anyway that I can add my own documentation to the standard Help functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've actually managed to find a workaround, albeit a nasty one: Because the OAuth functionality is handled further up the stack you can basically make a normal Action within a Controller which takes a "custom" object that conforms to the input expected by the actual OAuth endpoint. It will never be called because the OAuth endpoint handles the URI first, but it still shows up in the API Help.

Comment: Beautifull! Software development = the 'new' art. :D

Comment: kind of an awesome answer

Comment: I don't have a better answer, and still researching this. I, however, feel that this answer is dangerous. Anytime you update or change the token endpoint (not often I agree) you have to remember to change this fake endpoint

also developers coming into your project may believe the endpoint is real and not fake.

Comment: @PaulBinder I agree that it's not a nice solution, hence me describing it as a "nasty one".